# How to upload dummy data to Wakanda DataSource

Tags: json, upload, wakanda

I am newbie to building Wakanda projects, I have successfully built a dataModel with several dataClasses, I wish to populate these dataClasses with dummy generated data from using either SQL, JSON or CSV dump files.

Is it correct for me to assume, it would be best for me to use the data file in the JSON format and then upload this dummy data to the dataModel. I have been unable to find anywhere within Wakanda Studio to make this possible. Can someone tell/show me how best to populate the 1000 plus records of dummy data.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

I normally like to populate my database using the simple `loadText` function when parsing a **CSV** or the [`importFromJSON`](http://livedoc.wakanda.org/Wakanda0/help/Command/en/page901101.html) with **JSON** files.

1. First you need to create a `.js` file anywhere in your server-side part of the Project. `backend` and `database` folders are considered server-side.
2. You have to script the actions. You can see an [example here](https://github.com/jonathanargentiero/italian-beer-explorer-react/blob/master/italian-beer-explorer-react/database/data/importScript.js). If you are parsing a **CSV** file then use `loadText('/path/to/file.csv').split("\n")`otherwise use the [`importFromJSON`](http://livedoc.wakanda.org/Wakanda0/help/Command/en/page901101.html) for **JSON** files.
3. Run the script with the arrow button on the toolbar of the code editor.

The output is shown in the console on the bottom of the code editor.

Comment: Thanks I will give this a try.

Answer (score 3):

There is a [`importFromJSON( )`](http://livedoc.wakanda.org/Wakanda0/help/Command/en/page901101.html) method which compliments the [`exportAsJSON( )`](http://livedoc.wakanda.org/Wakanda0/help/Command/en/page900953.html) method.

If your JSON is coming from something other than Wakanda's `exportAsJSON` method then you may want to create a few records and then run the `exportAsJSON` to verify the format Wakanda is expecting. Then make sure your JSON is in the same format before using it with `importFromJSON`.

Comment: Thanks, thought I would look at try to use importFromJSON

Answer (score 1):

Here is my way to do an import from a JSON object.

You have to be aware to import the data in the correct order according to relationship. For example you cannot import first the employees and assign a company, because the companies doesn't exist yet. So the correct order here, is to import the companies and then import the employees and link the company associated.

```
/**
 * Example Data
 */

var hireDate = new Date('2012',7,13,1,0,0),
    companies = [{name:'Company 1'},{name:'Company 2'},{name:'Company 3'}],

    employees = [{firstName:'John',lastName:'Doe',company:'Company 1',hireDate:hireDate,salary:2000},
                    {firstName:'Frederic',lastName:'Smith',company:'Company 2',hireDate:hireDate,salary:2000},
                    {firstName:'John',lastName:'Doe',company:'Company 3',hireDate:hireDate,salary:3000},
                    {firstName:'Marc',lastName:'Petit',company:'Company 2',hireDate:hireDate,salary:5000},
                    {firstName:'Arthur',lastName:'Johns',company:'Company 3',hireDate:hireDate,salary:2500},
                    {firstName:'Mike',lastName:'Sina',company:'Company 3',hireDate:hireDate,salary:2900},
                    {firstName:'Jack',lastName:'Taylor',company:'Company 1',hireDate:hireDate,salary:7800},
                    {firstName:'Simon',lastName:'Portmann',company:'Company 2',hireDate:hireDate,salary:4700}],

    newCompany,newEmployee;

companies.forEach(function(company){
    newCompany = new ds.Company(company);
    newCompany.save();
});

employees.forEach(function(employee){
    newEmployee = new ds.Employee(employee);
    newEmployee.company = ds.Company.find('name == :1',employee.company)
    newEmployee.save();
});

ds.Employee.all()
```

If the attribute names are the same that in the dataClass you can just assign the object on the creation. Or you can manipulate the attribute if you have some special rules like that :

```
employees.forEach(function(employee){
    newEmployee = new ds.Employee();
    // Example how to assign value to an attribute on the import
    // newEmployee is the new employee created in the dataStore of Wakanda.
    // employee is the employee which come from the JSON object.
    // Maybe the imported data have different attribute names.
    newEmployee.firstName = employee.name;
    newEmployee.lastName = employee.lname;
    newEmployee.birthDate = new Date(employee.datestamp);
    newEmployee.company = ds.Company.find('name == :1',employee.company)
    newEmployee.save();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What I do is have a `.js` file that I created at the project-level. Inside that file is the code in the jsfiddle below. You'll see that when your solution is running, you are able to hit the "play" button above the editor window to run the script.

Be aware that your access to the Datastore Class will still be affected by any `validate()` or `restrict()` or `save()` etc. events that you have set on your Datastore class to restrict access / protect your data. Check out [`promoteWith()`](http://livedoc.wakanda.org/Users-and-Groups/Session/promoteWith.301-816924.en.html) and [`unPromote()`](http://livedoc.wakanda.org/Users-and-Groups/Session/unPromote.301-816946.en.html) if these restrictions get in your way.

My script loads a comma-delimited CSV from my `Backups` folder at the Project level. I put the javascript here for you to see:

https://jsfiddle.net/kgwd1kek/

I can expand on this if you like, I hope this helps.

Also, if you are referring to a Project other than the first/only one in your solution, you'll want to change the array index on line 2.

Also instead, you could put a `for` loop in that `.js` file that runs from 1-1000 creating records and saving them. I do this and even use a `Math.random()` [function I picked up from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random) to create records with random data. Even in the case with string data or booleans, I use the random number and a `switch()` statement to add one of many predetermined string values to the entity before saving. It's a great testing solution for me.